# when is a system of mass-action reactions guaranteed to satisfy detailed balance?

Tags: thermodynamics, kinetics

when does a system of mass-action reactions satisfy detailed balance for *any non-zero choice of the rate constants*?

consider a trivial example:

$X + Y \ce{<-->[k1][k2]} XY$

satisfies detailed balance for any $k_1, k_2 > 0$. Here is a less trivial example:

$A + X \ce{<-->[k1][k2]} AX$

$B + X \ce{<-->[k3][k4]} BX$

we can ask if this system satisfies detailed balance, ie whether for any cycle the product of the rates going clockwise must equal the product of the rates going counter-clockwise ([Wegscheider condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detailed_balance#:%7E:text=The%20Wegscheider%20conditions%20demonstrate%20that,all%20states%20far%20from%20equilibrium.))?

It appears that any positive non-zero values of $k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4$ this system satisfies Wegscheider. Is that right and if so is there a simple property of the *structure* of such reactions that we can check to tell if it will satisfy Wegscheider?

Comment: Where do you see a cycle her ?

Comment: @Maurice: AX is formed, then BX is formed (path 1) vs. BX is formed, then AX is formed (path 2)

Comment: Is it a cycle ?

Comment: @Maurice can you point to a definition of a true cycle or argue why this isn't a cycle?

Comment: @userip. A cycle is a series of reactions going from A to B, then from B to C, then from C to D, and then from D to A. For example NO plus O2 gives NO2, NO2 plus water gives HNO2 and HNO3, then HNO2 gets NO + HNO3, and NO is already obtained in smaller proportion, to start the cycle again. The final result, after many cycles is that all NO is transformed into HNO3.